# In a python iterator select other iterator based on conditions

Tags: python, iterator, pytorch

In python I have an iterator returning an infinite string of indices in a fixed range `[0, N]` called `Sampler`. Actually I have a list of those and all they do is return indices in the range `[0, N_0], [N_0, N_1], ..., [N_{n-1}, N_n].`

What I now want to do is first select one of these iterators based on the length of their range, so I have a `weights` list `[N_0, N_1 - N_0, ...]` and I select one of these with:

```
    iterator_idx = random.choices(range(len(weights)), weights=weights/weights.sum())[0]
```

Next, what I want to do is create an iterator which randomly selects one of the iterators and selects a batch of `M` samples.

```py
class BatchSampler:
    def __init__(self, M):
        self.M = M
        self.weights = [weight_list]

        self.samplers = [list_of_iterators]
        ]
        self._batch_samplers = [
            self.batch_sampler(sampler) for sampler in self.samplers
        ]

    def batch_sampler(self, sampler):
        batch = []
        for batch_idx in sampler:
            batch.append(batch_idx)
            if len(batch) == self.M:
                yield batch

        if len(batch) > 0:
            yield batch

    def __iter__(self):
        # First select one of the datasets.
        iterator_idx = random.choices(
            range(len(self.weights)), weights=self.weights / self.weights.sum()
        )[0]
        return self._batch_samplers[iterator_idx]
```

**The issue with this is that `iter()` only seems to be called once, so only the first time `iterator_idx` is selected. Obviously this is wrong... What is the way around this?**

This is a possible case when you would have multiple datasets in pytorch, but you want to sample only batches from one of the datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you want to define your own container type.
I'll try to provide examples of a few standard ways to do so
(hopefully without missing too many details);
you should be able to reuse one of these simple examples,
into your own class.

---

Using just __getitem__ (support indexing & looping):

[object.__getitem__](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getitem__#object.__getitem__)

> Called to implement evaluation of self[key].

```
class MyContainer:
  def __init__(self, sequence):
    self.elements = sequence  # Just something to work with.
  
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    # If we're delegating to sequences like built-in list, 
    # invalid indices are handled automatically by them 
    # (throwing IndexError, as per the documentation).
    return self.elements[key]

t = (1, 2, 'a', 'b')
c = MyContainer(t)
elems = [e for e in c]
assert elems == [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
assert c[1:-1] == t[1:-1] == (2, 'a')
```

---

Using the iterator protocol:

[object.__iter__](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__iter__#object.__iter__)

> object.__iter__(self)
> This method is called when an iterator is required for a container. This method should return a new iterator object that can iterate over all the objects in the container. For mappings, it should iterate over the keys of the container.
> Iterator objects also need to implement this method; they are required to return themselves. For more information on iterator objects, see Iterator Types.

[Iterator Types](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

> container.__iter__()
> Return an iterator object. The object is required to support the iterator protocol described below.

> The iterator objects themselves are required to support the following two methods, which together form the iterator protocol:
>
> iterator.__iter__()
> Return the iterator object itself. This is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the for and in statements.
>
> iterator.__next__()
> Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception.

> Once an iterator's __next__() method raises StopIteration, it must continue to do so on subsequent calls.

```
class MyContainer:
  class Iter:
    def __init__(self, container):
      self.cont = container
      self.pos = 0
      self.len = len(container.elements)
    
    def __iter__(self): return self
    def __next__(self):
      if self.pos == self.len: raise StopIteration
      curElem = self.cont.elements[self.pos]
      self.pos += 1
      return curElem
  
  def __init__(self, sequence):
    self.elements = sequence  # Just something to work with.
  
  def __iter__(self):
    return MyContainer.Iter(self)

t = (1, 2, 'a', 'b')
c = MyContainer(t)
elems = [e for e in c]
assert elems == [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
```

---

Using a generator:

[Generator Types](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types)

> Python's generators provide a convenient way to implement the iterator protocol. If a container object's **iter**() method is implemented as a generator, it will automatically return an iterator object (technically, a generator object) supplying the **iter**() and **next**() methods.

[generator](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-generator)

> A function which returns a generator iterator. It looks like a normal function except that it contains yield expressions for producing a series of values usable in a for-loop or that can be retrieved one at a time with the next() function.
> Usually refers to a generator function, but may refer to a generator iterator in some contexts.

[generator iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator)

> An object created by a generator function.

[6.2.9. Yield expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)

> Using a yield expression in a function's body causes that function to be a generator

```
class MyContainer:
  def __init__(self, sequence):
    self.elements = sequence  # Just something to work with.
  
  def __iter__(self):
    for e in self.elements: yield e

t = (1, 2, 'a', 'b')
c = MyContainer(t)
elems = [e for e in c]
assert elems == [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
```